What's the law if a person has zera levatalah when asleep
I heard that doing zera levatalah is like murder and correct me if I'm wrong the soul of the child that should have been put in a body tries to come back and do stuff to the person and after it has been brought into this world (although without a body).
And I heard there is ways to destroy these spirits as with having kavana with kiriyat shma al hamita although my question is about sleep.
What's the law if this happens when you sleep? One Rav told me it's not considered transgressing the prohibition of zera levatalah. What's the source of this?
Also, what if the transgression woke you up is it considered transgressing or even as severe as murder and if yes or no does it still create the spirits?

אונס רחמנא פטריה

This is covered by the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch. The text of the beracha itself should answer your other questions.

מִי שֶרָאָה, חַס וְשָׁלוֹם, קְרִי בַּלַּיְלָה, כְּשֶׁנֵּעוֹר
מִשְּׁנָתוֹ, יִטּוֹל יָדָיו
וְיֹּאמַר בְּשִׁבְרוֹן לֵב, רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶל עוֹלָם, עָשִׂיתִי זֹאת שֶׁלֹּא בְּכַוָּנָה, רַק בְּהִרְהוּרִים רָעִים וּבְמַחֲשָׁבוֹת רָעוֹת.
לָכֵן יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ, ה' אֱלֹהַי וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתַי, מְחַק
בְּרַחֲמֶיךָ הָרַבִּים עָוֹן זֶה, וְתַצִּילֵנִי מֵהִרְהוּרִים רָעִים
וְכַיוֹצֵא בָהֶם לְעוֹלָם וָעֶד, אָמֵן וְכֵן יְהִי רָצוֹן.
If, God forbid, you had a seminal emission at night, upon waking up from your sleep you should wash your hands [with a kos] and say with a contrite heart, "Master of the Universe I have done this unwittingly but it was due to sinful thoughts and sinful reflections; therefore, may it be Your will Ado-noy, my God, and the God of my fathers, to erase this iniquity through your great mercy, and save me from sinful thoughts, and from similar occurrences forever and ever. Amein, so may it be Your will."


This is what Rav Nachman's Tikkun HaKlali was made for. I recommend saying it as a tikkun. For information on it, see: https://www.tikkunhaklali.net/

So it wasn't made for intentional transgressors? (Asking for a friend)

all good, Tikkun halal was made for everything, hence the name "klali" general. specifically zero levatalo but Rav Nachman specifically says it helps for unintentional more; that being said, it also surely helps for intentional

What's the source that it surely helps for intentional? I'm pretty sure rav nachman's words were only for unintentional
